# Enable token exchange in Keycloak 15.0.2

Tags: keycloak, access-token, token-exchange

I need to enable token exchange feature in Keycloak 15.0.2 for my clients. I did lots of researches and tried the following:

- using --preview while starting the server (e.g. standalone.bat --preview=enabled): I faced an error.
- using -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled in after standalone.bat: I faced an error.
- Update configuration/standalone.xml and added  with default provider enabled: No error but the feature is not implemented 501 response.

  What should I do? I can't upgrade the Keycloak for now and I really need to enable this feature in Keycloak version 15.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure below 2 arugments

- -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled
  -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enable

Once feature is enabled you will get an permission tab in your idp.
there you can give token exchange permission.